# Can anyone tell me I'm getting `error invalid_request_error` on createChatCompletion of OpenAI

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

This is my code below:

```
const chatGPT = await openAI.createChatCompletion({
  model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
  messages: {
    role: 'user',
    content: 'Write an SEO Optimized Article selling Warli paintings for Home Decor items 
      within 500 words or less'
  }
});

console.log("API call completed");

console.log("result obtained", chatGPT.data.choices[0].message);
```

**Thanks for help in advance**!

Answer (score 1):

messages are to be expected as array of objects nothing more!